# Most efficient way to remove multiple substrings from string?

Tags: python, string, performance

What's the most efficient method to remove a list of substrings from a string?

I'd like a cleaner, quicker way to do the following:

```
words = 'word1 word2 word3 word4, word5'
replace_list = ['word1', 'word3', 'word5']

def remove_multiple_strings(cur_string, replace_list):
  for cur_word in replace_list:
    cur_string = cur_string.replace(cur_word, '')
  return cur_string

remove_multiple_strings(words, replace_list)
```

Comment: If the list is `['apple', 'banana']`, and the string is `'banappleana'`, should that become `''` or `'banana'`? Your current code would produce `''`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'|'.join(map(re.escape, replace_list)), '', words)
' word2  word4, '
```

The above one-liner is actually not as fast as your `string.replace` version, but definitely shorter:

```
>>> words = ' '.join([hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:10] for _ in xrange(10000)])
>>> replace_list = words.split()[:1000]
>>> random.shuffle(replace_list)
>>> %timeit remove_multiple_strings(words, replace_list)
10 loops, best of 3: 49.4 ms per loop
>>> %timeit re.sub(r'|'.join(map(re.escape, replace_list)), '', words)
1 loops, best of 3: 623 ms per loop
```

Gosh! Almost 12x slower.

But can we improve it? Yes.

As we are only concerned with words what we can do is simply filter out words from the `words` string using `\w+` and compare it against a set of `replace_list`(yes an actual `set`: `set(replace_list)`):

```
>>> def sub(m):
    return '' if m.group() in s else m.group()
>>> %%timeit
s = set(replace_list)
re.sub(r'\w+', sub, words)
...
100 loops, best of 3: 7.8 ms per loop
```

For even larger string and words the `string.replace` approach and my first solution will end up taking quadratic time, but the solution should run in linear time.

Comment: This is definitely cleaner, but is this faster?

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking!

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc: Dunno, but it definitely doesn't have the banappleana problem.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc It actually turned out to be slow, added a faster version.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Great improvement! +1

Comment: Why exactly do we need an actual `set`?

Comment: Looking up an item in a hash set is O(1) while looking up an item in a list is O(n)