# Python best way to remove multiple strings from string

Tags: python, string

Python 3.6

I'd like to remove a list of strings from a string. Here is my first poor attempt:

```
string = 'this is a test string'
items_to_remove = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'string']
result = list(filter(lambda x: x not in items_to_remove, string.split(' ')))
print(result)
```

output:

```
['test']
```

But this doesn't work if `x` isn't nicely spaced. I feel there must be a builtin solution, hmm There must be a better way!

I've had a look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606124/most-efficient-way-to-remove-multiple-substrings-from-string) on stack overflow, exact question as mine...

Not to waste my efforts. I timed all the solutions. I believe the easiest, fastest and most pythonic is the simple for loop. Which was not the conclusion in the other post...

```
result = string
for i in items_to_remove:
    result = result.replace(i,'')
```

Test Code:

```
import timeit

t1 = timeit.timeit('''
string = 'this is a test string'
items_to_remove = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'string']
result = list(filter(lambda x: x not in items_to_remove, string.split(' ')))
''', number=1000000)
print(t1)

t2 = timeit.timeit('''
string = 'this is a test string'
items_to_remove = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'string']
def sub(m):
    return '' if m.group() in items_to_remove else m.group()

result = re.sub(r'\w+', sub, string)
''',setup= 'import re', number=1000000)
print(t2)

t3 = timeit.timeit('''
string = 'this is a test string'
items_to_remove = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'string']
result = re.sub(r'|'.join(items_to_remove), '', string)
''',setup= 'import re', number=1000000)
print(t3)

t4 = timeit.timeit('''
string = 'this is a test string'
items_to_remove = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'string']
result = string
for i in items_to_remove:
    result = result.replace(i,'')
''', number=1000000)
print(t4)
```

outputs:

```
1.9832003884248448
4.408749988641971
2.124719851741177
1.085117268194475
```

Comment: There is a difference between those solutions - some will take into account full words, while others, like the `for` loop, will replace substrings as well.  Try changing the order of your `items_to_remove` to: `['is', 'this', 'a', 'string']` and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Ohh thats a great point!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `string.split()` if you aren't confident of your string spacing.

`string.split()` and `string.split(' ')` work a little differently:

```
In [128]: 'this     is   a test'.split()
Out[128]: ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']

In [129]: 'this     is   a test'.split(' ')
Out[129]: ['this', '', '', '', '', 'is', '', '', 'a', 'test']
```

The former splits your string without any redundant empty strings.

If you want a little more security, or if your strings could contain tabs and newlines, there's another solution with regex:

```
In [131]: re.split('[\s]+',  'this     is \t  a\ntest', re.M)
Out[131]: ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
```

Lastly, I would suggest converting your lookup list into a lookup `set` for efficient lookup in your filter:

```
In [135]: list(filter(lambda x: x not in {'is', 'this', 'a', 'string'}, string.split()))
Out[135]: ['test']
```

While on the topic of performance, a list comp is a bit faster than a filter, although less concise:

```
In [136]: [x for x in string.split() if x not in {'is', 'this', 'a', 'string'}]
Out[136]: ['test']
```

Comment: That's gold, couple of subtle things i didn't consider