# Remove special characters except space in an list without using re - Python

Tags: python

I have the list lst= ["is ", "star,", "the-"] and I want to remove ',', '-' without using re.

I used the below and it works but I wondered if there is something simpler:

```
words = []
index = 0
length = 0

for char in lst:
    for i, c in enumerate(char):
        if c.isalpha():
            if length == 0:
                index = i
            length += 1
        else:
            word = char[index:index + length]
            words.append(word)
            length = 0
print(words)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient way to remove multiple substrings from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606124/most-efficient-way-to-remove-multiple-substrings-from-string) The question itself, not the answer...

Comment: lst = [x.replace(",").replace("-") for x in lst]

Comment: Or better: [How to replace multiple substrings of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string) (23 answers...)

Comment: No, if you notice in my case, I need to replace several symbols, while the replace allows replacing one unless I don't do replace on replace which I don't want.

Comment: Can you, please, suggest merging my question, again? As I cannot delete the question.

Comment: If any gold-badger happens to pass by here, this is a much more accurate duplicate: [Remove all special characters, punctuation and spaces from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843518/remove-all-special-characters-punctuation-and-spaces-from-string?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you:

```
lst = ["is ", "star,", "the-"] 
lst = [''.join(e for e in f if e.isalpha()) for f in lst] 
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['is', 'star', 'the']
```

Comment: Sweet but I would rather use a method to remove all special symbols.

Comment: @eponkratova, just Edited, using just one line of Code!

Comment: Thank you! Closed the question as the duplicated.

Comment: @eponkratova the output has the whitespace removed. Is this what you want?

Comment: Actually, when I think about it, the space should be removed, thus, the solution gets the required result. Thus, the solution by ATIF also should be modified and include only the comparison range.

Comment: @eponkratova, Don't worry about  question closing. Now, have i answered you as you expected? whats about the white-space character, do you want to remove them also?

Comment: Yes, you did answer in a simpler way! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in lower case characters, you could use python's in built ord method.

```
for idx, word in enumerate(words):
    new_word = ""
    for char in word:
        if char == " " or 97 <= ord(char) <= 122:
            new_word += char
    words[idx] = new_word
```

Comment: it works, thank you! I will accept you answer in 6 min.

Comment: It would be alot more clear to do a simple [`char.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) instead of `97 <= ord(char) <= 122`

Comment: yes but i think the requirement is lower case characters and isalpha would be true for both upper and lower case characters

Comment: Well there are no examples with upper case letters but the requirement is to remove special characters so I would guess all letters should be accepted...

Answer (score 0):

```
words = []
for word in lst:
    #clean_word: loop the word and check every single value if it is alphanumeric, append and pass if it is a special characters or spaces. It will become a list since we do list comprehension (['i', 's']) and join them to become a string ('is').
    clean_word = [letter for letter in word if letter.isalnum()]
    words.append(''.join(clean_word))
print (words)
```

Comment: I already now added the explanation at the top of the variable clean_word.